# Is it in NP to check if the convex hull contains the unit ball?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, cg.comp-geom

Given a set of $n$ points in $d$ dimensional Euclidean space, the problem is to determine if the convex hull contains the unit ball centered at the origin.

> Is this problem in NP?

It is in co-NP as one can give a point in the ball outside the convex hull as a witness and verify this fact using linear programming.

My focus here is not in computer precision relating to square roots although this may also be interesting.

(Related to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/141782/efficiently-determine-if-convex-hull-contains-the-unit-ball .)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is NP-hard; see my answer at [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/141782/efficiently-determine-if-convex-hull-contains-the-unit-ball). Thus there is no polynomial-size certificate that the unit ball is contained in the convex hull of given points unless $\text{NP} = \text{co-NP}$ (if $\text{NP} = \text{co-NP}$ then the polynomial hierarchy collapses).

Comment: This seems to imply the problem is both NP-hard and in co-NP. Doesn't this imply that co-NP contains NP which seems rather surprising (to say the least). Or is that not right?

Comment: The problem is in co-NP; it is co-NP complete. It is NP-hard w.r.t. to Cook reductions.